# how can we hide json data to ajax from tools inspector

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel-5, httpresponse

I need to hide the response JSON from from tools inspector. how can we hide json data from tools inspector? or show only the value of field and don't the name of field? 
this is the response of function in laravel : `return \Response::json($posts);`
[image]

Comment: If the user shouldn't see the data, don't send it to the user. If they're supposed to see that data, why does it matter if they can see it in the inspector?

Comment: (See also: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

Comment: no, my idea is hide the name of field, i.e name : Bils

Comment: example hide the attibute name in this response. ({name : bils})

Comment: Why? Surely the user can tell that "New York" is probably the city, and that "John" is the name. Why are your attribute names secret? Sure, you could manually return an array of data and use array indexes, or make nonsensical attribute names with a transformer or directly in the database, but **what's the point?** What are you trying to accomplish? You have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, I suspect.

Comment: this is a simple example, i have other attribute that i do not want the user or even exploit by attacker

Comment: Then you should read up on why "security by obscurity" doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Simply **you can't**.

If you are serving those json as a response, then the response can be inspected with all the attributes you provided.

One posible solution is to make the response more hard to read for humans, this type of method is called [Obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)).

Comment: I need to hide the attibute name in this response. ({name : bils})

Answer (score 0):

**It is not possible** anything that is sent to the browser has to be visible to end user and it is fact. Javascript/JSON are for client-side language/object, and so they will be available to the user all the time.